# Adding an EventListener to button

Tags: javascript

i have an `input[type="text"]` that when i press the down key, it adds focus to a button.

```
if(e.keyCode == 40 && document.getElementsByClassName('list-item').length > 0){
    document.getElementsByClassName('list-item')[0].focus();
    console.log(document.activeElement);
}
```

I want to know if it's possible for me to add an eventListener to keyboard events on a button, even if the button is a `input[type="button"]` or a `<button>` tag. I've added two events that worked, and the two events that are relative to the keyboard are not working. Is that possible?

```
            collection[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
                console.log('click');
            });
            collection[i].addEventListener('focus', function(e){
                console.log('focus');
            })
            collection[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
                console.log('keyup');
            })
            collection[i].addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
                console.log('keypress');
            })
```

*ps: i don't want any jquery*

Comment: A fiddle would help a lot

Comment: Works for me, but the button must of course be focused -> http://jsfiddle.net/7gfq0x69/

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation, `keypress` only works for keys that produce a character value. As @adeneo mentioned, `keyup` seems to work on the down key. The trick is to be focused on the button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress